# Function of {} \;

Tags: bash, shell

I'm currently pawing through a Unix tutorial and I've been met with this:

```
find ~ -name test3* -ok rm {}\;
```

I'm curious as to what the `{}\;` does.

Comment: This construct is particular to find (indeed to `-exec` and other find flags that *run* some command). You might check the manpage, I've forgotten exactly what it's about except that `\;` is to prevent the shell from interpreting the `;`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `{}\;` string tells *find*(1) that (a) the file name is to be substituted in place of the `{}`, and (b) that the commands ends at the ";". The ";" has to be escaped (hence the backslash) because it has special meaning to the shell. For that same reason, you really ought to quote the 'test3*' string. You want *find* to expand that, not the shell. If there happen to be matching files in the directory where you run *find*, you're not going to get the results you expect.

Thus, you're telling *find*(1) to run "rm" on every file it finds.

There's a more efficient solution to that particular problem, though:

```
find . -name 'test3*' -print | xargs rm -f
```

Comment: I always use `rm -f`. Even if *find* finds the file, there's no guarantee *rm* will be able to remove it.

Comment: Your command removes the file unconditionally. The asker's command prompts for each file.

Comment: Fair enough, but somewhat beside the point. (`xargs rm -f` rolls off my fingers automatically, no doubt due to 25 years of using Unix systems.)

Comment: xargs (when not using -print0, anyway) is *not safe*.  All you need is one filename with a space or \n in and *really bad things can happen*.  (The usual response I get to this is 'people who put spaces in a filename deserve everything they get'.  This makes me want to punch people, so find a better argument. ;)

Comment: So use -print0 and `xargs -0`. It's why they're there.